# Hover text, change some letters temporary

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```js
$("#hole").mouseover(function() {
  $("#text").text("At random, some letters from the previous text should be replaced with this emoji: ");
});
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 40px;
  cursor: crosshair;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#hand {
  position: fixed;
  transform: scale(0);
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: transform 1.2s linear;
}

#hole:hover~#hand {
  position: fixed;
  transform: scale(20);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>

<div id="hole">️</div>
<div id="hand"></div>
```

If you hover the hole emoji, some letters from the text should be randomly and temporary replaced with .

What is the easiest way to do that? Does it make sense to start with `.text("...")`? And then there should be a random function integrated?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what research you've done. For instance, we have a number of questions on Stack Overflow on [how to replace random letters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+to+replace+random+letters+in+a+string+%5Bjavascript%5D+is%3Aq).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get the text of the element you wish to change to your `ok` symbol. Then `split` the string at each character. Define an empty array to hold the new array with the changed character to `okay` symbol. Then iterate over the `el.split()` array using `$.each()`.

I use a helper function to reassign the new array with the values using a conditional. Check if the value in the array is equal to the randomly selected value, if it is, we change its value to the `okay` symbol in the new array when we map the values using the helper function.

lastly, we join the array to create the string to place in the text of the element.

```js
let assign = (array, index, newValue) => {
    array[index] = newValue;
    return array;
}

$("#hole").mouseover(() => {
  const arr = $("#text").text().split(' ')
  const random = arr[~~(Math.random() * arr.length)]
  const changed = [];
    $.each(arr, (i,val) => {
      val === random ?
        assign(changed, i, ''):
        assign(changed, i, val)   
    })
    $("#text").text(changed.join(" "))
});
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 40px;
  cursor: crosshair;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#hand {
  position: fixed;
  transform: scale(0);
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: transform 1.2s linear;
}

#hole:hover~#hand {
  position: fixed;
  transform: scale(20);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>

<div id="hole">️</div>
<div id="hand"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the most simplest code to achieve this. There are a lot of complex ways which will achieve this more cleanly and with efficiency. But considering you are a beginner I have tried to not use any complex function here.

```
$("#hole").mouseover(function () {
  var arr = $("#text").text();

  //Randomly select how many letters do we have to change.
  var numChangeLetters = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  for (var i = 0; i <= numChangeLetters; i++) {
    //Randomly select an index.
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    //Strings are immutable in JavaScript. That's why we have to change it like this.
    arr = arr.substring(0, index) + '' + arr.substring(index + 1);
  }
  $("#text").text(arr);
})
```